# VS2008 Ignores location of MyDocuments? Have the hardcoded this?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I recenty moved my MyDocuments folder onto another partition which I'm using for data. (Via the MyDocuments properties).

However, VS2008 is now crashing each time I try to open certain files.  I noticed that it has started putting files in MyDocuments on the old partition. Why is it ignoring the environment settings?  Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, you still have the old path to your documents folder specified in the Visual Studio options. It should have automatically found and used the correct path to the "My Documents" folder, wherever it was located, during installation, but since you changed the location since, it probably hasn't updated your private settings.

To verify this, open your Options dialog from the Tools menu, click on "Projects and Solutions" in the list, and confirm that the paths shown on the right are correct:

[image: Visual Studio Projects and Solutions options]

Comment: Hi Cody, Thanks.  Yes these were incorrect, but I had updated them.  The problem seems to have stemmed from the /Settings/CurrentSettings.vssettings file.  As far as I know there is no dialog to specify the location of this. I have just 'imported' the file from the new location, and for now it seems ok - we'll see.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: The Options dialog is what sets the settings in the `CurrentSettings.vssettings` file. And if you moved the location of your My Documents folder, I would assume that you moved its current contents along with it.

Comment: @Cody, Not sure what you mean.  None of the three fields in the dialog affect where the vssettings file is found.  It's normally in ...Visual Sudio 2008\Settings.  The dialog you've show only affects the Projects and Templates folders, which are siblings of the Settings folder.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: Yes, that's the second sentence of my last comment. I assumed that you moved the all of the *current* contents of the My Documents folder to the new location when you remapped it. That means your CurrentSettings file would have already been in the new location. But whatever, it sounds like you got it working.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: And, for what it's worth, you can set where Visual Studio saves your settings file in the Options dialog, too. Expand the "Environment" heading, and click "Import and Export Settings".

Comment: It would have been so much easier if they just let you point to a new root VS folder!